# How to mark a file as unmodified in CVS

Tags: cvs

I checked out a file, and then I changed it, but I don't want to commit the change. Is there a way to fake CVS into thinking that the file is not modified?  I want something similar to the "flush" command in Perforce.

I am using TortoiseCVS and command line.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is different between your version and the server's CVS will think it is modified and needs to be submitted. Your best bet is to explicitly list the files you want to checkin when you run 'cvs commit'.

Comment: ok, well, that's probably the best I can do.  I am using Eclipse with the Project browser, and when a project is modified it puts a little arrow '>' next to the project.  So now ALL my projects have that '>' next to them, which is a little annoying.  All I did is make a change to the .classpath file, and I do not want to commit that file (it would mess up other developers). I guess I could edit the "CVS/Entries" file and remove the line for that file.  Yikes!